# getting error like this "422 Unprocessable Entity"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post

I want to create a `POST` method URL. For that I did below code.

**home_controller.rb**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index_post
    puts"----------------#{params}----------#{request.method}"
  end
end
```

**route.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post 'home/index_post'
end
```

**index_post.html.erb**

```
<%= params %>
```

**application.html.erb**

```
 <%= link_to "index_post", home_index_post_path(:data => params[:data]), method: :post %>
```

Now I am trying to get response like below

```
data="test"
```

I am testing it on here https://www.hurl.it/

```
method =POST
```

`URL=amzone-ses-demo.herokuapp.com/home/index_post
paramiters= data = test`

getting an error like below

```
422 Unprocessable Entity
```

Please help me to solve this its IMP for me.
Thanks, in advance.

Comment: What format are you trying to return? Most clients would expect HTML or JSON, but you are returning the result of a `puts`, which is `nil`. Your controller action needs to render a view or a partial.

Comment: i just want to see whatever data i get

Comment: See it how? The server has to respond in some format, typically HTML or JSON. What format do you want to receive? Also, if you just want to see something, why are you using POST? Would GET be more appropriate?

Comment: currently, lets thing its HTML

Comment: What does the server log show? It should start with something like, `Started POST "/home/index_post" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2017-10-02 xx:xx:xx` and it should end with `Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in xxxms`. Please post the entire log response from Started to Completed in your question.

Comment: It works when I tried it. How did you get the error?

Comment: skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
 Added this line in a home controller but i am not sure that this is a right way ot not?

Comment: What you exactly do to get this error? Code looks strange but it didn't return 422 in my case.  I recommend you to use scaffold e.g. `bin/rails generate scaffold HighScore game:string score:integer` and then based on it build your own logic